# Octave: No Support for Excel

Tags: excel, matlab, octave, xls

I recently downloaded Octave as I need to convert a .mat file to a .xls.

I imported the .mat file to the program then ran this code:
`xlswrite('Elettra.xls', 'elettra_processed_data.mat')`

But I got this error back:

```
Creating file Elettra.xls
Supported interfaces: 
warning: No support for Excel .xls I/O
error: oct2xls: unknown Excel .xls interface - NONE.
error: called from:
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\io-1.0.11\oct2xls.m at line 100, column 3
error:   C:\Octave\3.2.4_gcc-4.4.0\share\octave\packages\io-1.0.11\xlswrite.m at line 160, column 6
>> Variables in the current scope:

 Name                 Size             Class           Bytes       
 ====                 ====             =====           =====        
 ans                  1x11             cell            92          
 dirlist              1x6              cell            18          
 ii                   1x1              double          8           
 old_format           1x45             char            45          
 processedData        1x1              struct          3978113     

Total is 64 elements using 3978276 bytes
```

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm not too familiar with this program.

Comment: Are you just trying to write data to an excel file?  If so why not just load it in matlab and use xlswrite?  Maybe I'm not understanding the need to use Octave here.

Comment: I'm betting that he doesn't have access to a Matlab license.

Answer (score 0):

Your title says it.  Octave has no built-in support for reading/writing from Excel, since the xlswrite function uses Windows COM. That having been said, there are [options that include using pure java](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/xlswrite-for-mac-linux/), discussed on the blog [Undocumented Matlab](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/).

What do you mean " convert a .mat file to a .xls"  Do you mean that you want to read in the data in the mat file and write it out in Excel? If so, they you will need to roll up your sleeves if you don't have proper Matlab.

Comment: I don't have a copy of MatLab, I saw Octave as the open source alternative. I did see a trial version of MatLab so would that still have the feature I need.

Basically in the data, there should be columns of lat, lon, positions and other data sets which I need to import on this database, but all the other datasets I have used are saved in a .csv file so I can open them in Excel. Unless you have any other ideas?

Comment: Actually, is there a way I can write to a .csv (as that is actually what I need) Something like writecsv?

Answer (score 0):

You could first load the data with

```
load elettra_processed_data.mat
```

then there should be your struct "processedData 1x1 struct 3978113" in the current scope. Since I don't know what is in the struct you could find out by just calling the name

```
processedData
```

there will be an output giving you the names of the subelements of the struct (maybe with a lots of data):

```
processedData =
{
   lat = ...
   lon = ... 
   positions = ...
}
```

if you find the data you would like to save (lets say it's in positions) you can call

```
csvwrite("Elettra.csv", processedData.positions);
```

and the Elettra.csv you can open with Excel.